# Xamarin forms Add reference to Web service

Tags: c#, rest, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

so I'm creating an app with Xamarin Forms Portable and I want to use a Web service that I hosted in Azure. As far as I know, I can't add a reference by right clicking on the Reference tab in the PCL project... So I wonder if anyone could provide me with a fairly simple and straight forward solution?

Comment: You could include the dll as a file. Add > Existing file

Comment: Do you want to refer Web Api?  Or use the endpoints in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change to Pcl profile 78.

Ok to do so... Right Click , properties on the PCL Project.

Uncheck Windows Phone 8.
Check Windows Phone Silverlight.

You are now using Profile78! Allowing you to add Silverlight WCF client :).

Wish this was documented better.

You can see what profile you are currently using by opening the proj file in notepad.

Happy Xamarining!

Comment: How do I change that? :) @Cyberpass

Comment: Thanks! I managed to figure it out. It works if I uninstall the Xamarin.Forms(only in PCL project) package then uncheck Windows Phone 8. Check Windows Phone Silverlight and then reinstall Xamarin.Forms package.

Comment: how do I target windows too if I will remove windows targets?

Answer (score 1):

References can be added if your project targets does not connect windows. Right click the PCL project and change the targets, remove windows.

Comment: When I try to uncheck Windows I get the following message: "The following will be automatically targeted because they support the same set of portable APIs: Windows 8" @Akash Amin

Comment: Remove all windows targets available.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what it looks like: [link](http://imgur.com/Ezybz8L) and when i press ok, it's still checked. @Akash Amin

Comment: As in the screenshot remove Windows Phone 8.1 also from the options. It says this because Windows 8 and Windows phone 8.1 support the same set of Portable references. No windows option must be checked. After that you will be able to add a service reference in the PCL project.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you have WindowsPhone project targeting your PCL. Reason for this is because you changed target from Windows Phone 8/8.1 to Windows Phone SIlverlight 8/8.1 so both libraires don't have same target. Basically, there is no way to make WCF service run for WindowsPhone.

Answer (score -1):

you can use application => "Service Reference Generator For .net Standard & Xamarin.Forms" from : https://files.fm/u/mduffseg

first read help in application